# Android Process Creation

Tags: android

why in android for each process there is seperate user profile is created?
I am asking about the working of the android operating system kernel.
There is a best feature of multi-threading is available for us so also mention while this feature does not useful in handset devices.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Security.  They do this so that each process runs in isolation and they can't interfere with each other.